# How does the assumption that E(u|x) = 3 bias OLS estimators?

Tags: regression, least-squares

Let's assume that the assumption of independence between X and the error term are violated.  So, for example, E(u|x) = 3 instead of 0. I was told this would B0 by 3, but this isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need strixt exogeneity, $E\left[x_{t}\left|x_{1},\:\dots,\, x_{T}\right.\right]=0$
  to show that the OLS estimator is unbiased. The OLS estimator is given as $\hat{\beta}=\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}Y
 $ and $Y=X\beta+\varepsilon
 $

Then write: $${\hat{\beta}=\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}y}
 $$
$$\hat{\beta}=\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\left(X\beta+\varepsilon\right)
  $$
$${\hat{\beta}=\underset{I}{\underbrace{\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}X}}\beta+\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\varepsilon}
 $$
$${\hat{\beta}=\beta+\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\varepsilon}, \, Eq.(1)$$ 
Now take conditional expectation of Eq. (1): 
$$E\left[\hat{\beta}\left|X\right.\right]=\beta+E\left[\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}\varepsilon\left|X\right.\right]
$$ $$E\left[\hat{\beta}\left|X\right.\right]=\beta+\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}E\left[\varepsilon\left|X\right.\right]$$

If $E\left[x_{t}\left|x_{1},\:\dots,\, x_{T}\right.\right]=0
 $ then the previous expression reduces to $E\left[\hat{\beta}\left|X\right.\right]=\beta
 $. If, however, ${E\left[x_{t}\left|x_{1},\:\dots,\, x_{T}\right.\right]=3}
 $ then the previous expression becomes ${E\left[\hat{\beta}\left|X\right.\right]=\beta+\left(X^{\prime}X\right)^{-1}X^{\prime}3}
 $ and you have shown that the OLS estimator is biased.